# MS graph API: 400 AuthenticationError with "/me/onlineMeetings" request

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an online meeting and recover its URL like explained here in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript), but when the request is run I get this error:

```
{ 
    "statusCode": 400,
    "code": "AuthenticationError",
    "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
    "requestId": "652ea3be-6a97-47e8-bfc6-3d7d1d51d425",
    "date": "2020-09-01T12:53:41.000Z",
    "body": "{
        "code":"AuthenticationError",
        "message":"Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError":{
            "date":"2020-09-01T13:53:41",
            "request-id":"652ea3be-6a97-47e8-bfc6-3d7d1d51d425"
        }
    }"
}
```

I tried also the get started projet for JS and it's working fine so I can't spot the problem.

here is what I used:

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'my_app_id',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    forceRefresh: false
  }
};

const loginRequest = { scopes: [
    'openid',
    'profile',
    'user.read',
    'calendars.read',
    'User.Read.All',
    'User.Export.All'
  ]
}
const options = new MicrosoftGraph.MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions([
    'user.read',
    'calendars.read',
    'OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite'
  ]);

const onlineMeeting = {
  startDateTime:"2020-09-01T16:00:34.2444915-07:00",
  endDateTime:"2020-09-01T16:30:34.2464912-07:00",
  subject:"test meeting"
};
const authProvider = new MicrosoftGraph.ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(msalClient, options);
// Initialize the Graph client
const graphClient = MicrosoftGraph.Client.initWithMiddleware({authProvider});

// then I call this inside an async function
let events = await graphClient.api('/users/my_UserPrincipalName/onlineMeetings').post(onlineMeeting);
//let events = await graphClient.api('/me/onlineMeetings').post(onlineMeeting);
// I tried with both calls and none of them worked
```

and here are the permissions on azure active directory:
[image]

So any ideas on how to solve this ?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a correct access token.

Since [Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) only supports **Delegated (work or school account)** permission type, you need to get the access token with Auth code flow or Implicit flow.

The started project for JS is using Implicit flow. So you can use Implicit flow to get the access token.

Here is the example in Postman:

[image]

The `Auth URL` above is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`.

[image]

Comment: thanks I was able to retrieve the access token as you explained, but now I'm wondering where should I add in my code, or even in postman to test it. I tried adding in the "Authorization" tab but it didn't work, it tells me "onlinemeeting cannot be null.", so what should I do ?

Comment: @Green Please see my second screenshot. In addition to setting the "Authorization" tab, you also need to set the body.

Comment: indeed the problem in postman was that I used "Text" instead of "JSON" as Content-Type, now it's working fine in postman, which makes me wonder why it doesn't work in my JS code, I thought that the MSAL should take care of the authorization without me needing to manage the tokens manually? so should I abandon using MSAL and just build all the requests myself?

Comment: @Green Sorry for the delay. I thought I replied to you before:\. I think msal.js should handle the authorization with `ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider`. You don't need to manage the tokens manually. But why are you saying it doesn't work in JS code? In your original post you mentioned "I tried also the get started project for JS and it's working fine". What is the error you are facing now? Add more details in the post if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work in my code:
let's call my user, which I used all this time, user "A", all I did is that I simply created another user "B" in Azure Active Directory and then logging in with this new user "B" in the login screen instead of the admin user "A" that I used before..... and now it's working.[image]

But this does not explain the issue, so if anyone can explain the difference or why it didn't work with the first account, that would be very helpful.